# problem with reset series points in teechart pro Delphi

Tags: delphi, vcl, teechart, delphi-10.1-berlin

I use Teechart pro VCL v2018.24.18 32bit.
I wrote some code that plots a chart from input data, which the user can save in a file or DB.

I have one problem, however. This process may be repeated several times, and I need create a new project. I reset the series value before receiving new input data:

```
 if DbChart1.SeriesCount <> 0 then     // clear all series data
 begin
   for dp := 0 to DbChart1.SeriesCount-1   do
   begin
      DbChart1.Series[dp].Clear;
      DbChart1.Series[dp].XValues.FillSequence;
      DbChart1.Series[dp].YValues.FillSequence;
      dbchart1.Series[dp].CleanupInstance;
   end;
 end;
  Dbchart1.BottomWall.EndPosition := 0;
  Dbchart1.LeftWall.EndPosition := 0;
  Dbchart1.DepthAxis.Maximum := 0;
```

All series points have been removed except the last point!
I want the serial to be clean, like the first time the program ran. How do I do this?

Comment: What is`FillSequence` intended for ?

Comment: I use it according to some tips. i think it can renumber points

Comment: It's enough ti make Clear, seems other operations are redundant

Comment: when i click on button this code clear the chart but after that i want to receive data for the second or third time the last point of previous data is still here

Comment: OK, perhaps receiving data gives such behaviour?

Comment: data(some numbers) read with comport and add points with this code " Series0.AddXY(x, y, '', clTeeColor)" . maybe there are another way for reset series in teechart !

Comment: From comport? So why **DB**chart? I've never seen old data after Clear. It is worth to create and show minimal reproducible example.

Comment: yes. I use Tvacomm for reading data . i use Mysql for save data and Dbchart  give me better options for work with database. i'm so confused. there are more than 3000 lines of codes and i check it several time and i have not any idea !! i want take a video, may be helpful to realize what happens . but where can i upload it ?

Comment: If this issue is due to DBchart peculiarities - I have no ideas, sorry, I worked only with non-database TChart.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.  the last point in series do not remove ( why ? maybe a Bug ).at the first i use another codes for remove  points but problem not solved. look at this codes :

```
With Dbchart1.Series[0] Do
Begin
   dec:=series0.Count;
   if dec<>0 then
   begin
      Series0.Delete(0,dec,true);
   end;
End;
```

but with repeat the codes the problem solved :

```
With Dbchart1.Series[0] Do
Begin
   dec:=series0.Count;
   label44.Caption := inttostr(dec);
   if dec<>0 then
   begin
      Series0.Delete(0,dec,true);
      dec:=series0.Count;
      Series0.Delete(0,dec,true);
   end;
End;
```